# php change post data to variable

Tags: php, arrays, post, foreach, global

I'm trying to change given $_POST data to variable format, here is my code:

```
<?php
$_POST["abc"]=2;
$post = array("abc");

foreach($post as $field) {
    global $field;
    $field = $_POST[$field];
}

echo $abc;
?>
```

but when I'm trying to run this code, I only get:

> PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: abc in /var/www/ on line 8

How can I change chosen POST variables in loop to normal variables? (eg. $_POST["abc"] to $abc)

Comment: Not 100% sure what you are doing, but think you want to use variabel variables: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can tried with [PHP variable variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

```
<?php
$_POST["abc"]=2;
$post = array("abc");

foreach($post as $field) {
     global $$field;
     $$field = $_POST[$field];
}

echo $abc;

?>
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the [extract](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) function

```
extract($_POST)
```

Comment: That is very insecure, because it is transforming any posted variable to local variable. You can add option EXTR_SKIP but still you have to keep in mind that, anyone can insert what-they-want variables to your code. I would not recomend this to any security-important script

Comment: That's true but als inherent to OPs question.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get the $_POST key as direct variable conversion you can use following script.

```
<?php

$_POST["abc"]=2;
$_POST["xyz"]=5;

$post = $_POST;
foreach($post as $key=>$field) {
    $$key = $field;
}

echo $abc . "<br/>";  //2
echo $xyz;  //5

?>
```

Here "$$" used to create variable in dynamic way from another string output.

Working sample available here: http://sugunan.net/demo/fof.php

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be:

```
 $abc = $_POST['abc'];
```

or

```
 list($abc,$def,$etc) = array($_POST['abc'],$_POST['abc'],$_POST['def'],$_POST['etc']);
```

or

```
  $postNeeded = array("abc","def","etc");
  foreach($postNeeded as $variable){ 
         if(isset($_POST[$variable])){
             ${$variable} = $_POST[$variable]; 
  }}
```

and so on for every variable i need from $_POST, your approach will make you vulnerable to code injection if the $_POST is not cleaned.
With time, I ended up using simply $_POST['var'] instead of extra variables, but depends on the project of course.
I hope my answer helps. GL.